# What was Bubble's fate?

Tags: valerian-and-city-thousand-planets, valerian-and-laureline

In her previous scenes we see that Bubble is practically impervious to any physical damage as she can alter her body so she won't get hit or damaged.

**So what happened to Bubble in her last scene?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [official novelisation](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/33216612-valerian-and-the-city-of-a-thousand-planets) indicates that she was repeatedly stabbed while defending Valerian. There's no special indication that, even as a shapeshifter, her body is capable of taking that kind of damage.

> *The fact that the guards didn’t appear to have much in the way of
> armor—well, much in the way of any kind of clothing, really—made it
> that much easier. They did know how to use their weapons, but he
> seemed to be quick enough to dodge them without any harm.*
>
> [after]
>
> *The fight… Valerian had fought like a madman, certain that the blades
> wielded by the guards weren’t even touching him because he was just
> that good. Of course the weapons hadn’t struck him—Bubble had
> protected him with her own body, taking blows meant for him. He hadn’t
> even thought about her—he was too busy being headstrong, impulsive
> Valerian. And now—*

Comment: Oh. So she shielded him. My initial guess was that she had enough of the generic and mushy hero so she'd opted out.